# How do I properly align images and text in html?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a lot of difficulties with correctly aligning my html code. I'm building a website and I have a page where I show off my projects. I need to have the image on the left hand side and the text to go on the right. However, I want there to be some space between the image and the text describing the image. I also want to have a limit as to how far the text goes before it starts typing on a new line. Right now, the text goes on and on, filling the entire horizontal line before it finally jumps to the next line. Here's my code:

```
 <style>

    a {
        color: #404040;
    }

    .bg-1 {
        background-color: #6DBDD6;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .container-fluid {
        padding-top: 80px;
        padding-bottom: 80px;

    }

    .img-1 {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 100px;
    }

  </style>



<div class="container-fluid bg-1">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href=""><img src="" class="img-1" height="281" width="388.9" alt="git"></a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h2>Project Name</h2> 
      <p>Created using java, this application allows for blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>

      <a href="">Click here to view full code!</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle and/or a screenshot of what you have so far and another rough sketch of what you want.

Comment: Heres a screenshot of what it does right now: http://imgur.com/a/fKdu8.

Notice how the text is right next to the image and how the text goes on and on until the edge of the right hand side of the screen. I want to know how to customize these two features.

Answer (score 0):

First don't use `col-sm-` class to the tag of image and the text, as it is defined as the column in bootstrap.

use your additional tags in one `col-sm`

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <img class="theimg" src="blah.jpg"/>
    <div class="parag">sdadasd</div>
</div>
```

And then you can float the child element to `left`

```
  .col-sm-8 .theimg, 
  .col-sm-8 .parag {
     float:left;
     margin:2px;  
  }
```

Here is the [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Klaudia/wp3Lzj4y/1/)

Comment: I'm sorry al_kasih_empatix but this didn't do anything for me. It shot the text all the way to the right hand side of the screen.

Comment: Yes I already saw that in the original post. It's still not helping me to customize the distance between the image and the paragraph.